# Lifecycle management rule not working for ADLS Gen2 Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am a newbie in using Azure and its technology stack. So apologies if I have not used the correct terms here.

I am an admin on the Azure portal for the respective workspace and the storage account. I have set up a rule to hard delete the file from my test "Block" type blob container / Archive directory to delete the files older than 1 day. It has been a week since I created that rule but the files have not been deleted yet. Any ideas why would that be? Here is the code view of the rule that I have set up.

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "30daysStorage",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "loadfilestest/Archive/"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Were the blobs already there when you created the rule? It's possible it only applies to new blobs.

Comment: Hi @JoelCochran, Good catch. They were indeed already present in the container subdirectory when the rule was created. I just deleted them manually and reprocessed my pipeline. I will comment here again to update you and others.

Comment: Hi @JoelCochran, the rule performed the deletion as expected. Thanks for your guidance on this.

Comment: Glad it worked. You should be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The files that already exist at the time of the creation of the lifecycle management rule, will not be purged as the rule applies only to the files created after the rule is created.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.