# Azure file deletion not working with life cycle management rule

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

We have a requirement to delete the files after certain days from storage container folders.

I have set a rule to delete them as per below. But looks like this rule is not getting triggered. Please advice.

`````
"rules": [
{
"enabled": true,
"name": "test",
"type": "Lifecycle",
"definition": {
"actions": {
"baseBlob": {
"delete": {
"daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 1
}
}
},
"filters": {
"blobTypes": [
"blockBlob"
],
"prefixMatch": [
"raw / BV/ landing / BV-data-to-Data-Lake-Integration/events",
"raw / BV/ landing / BV-data-to-Data-Lake-Integration/event_",
"raw / BV/ landing / BV-data-to-Data-Lake-Integration/sensors"
]
}
}
}
]
}````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got the result successfully:**

> I have set a rule to delete them as per below. But looks like this rule is not getting triggered.

- If you not getting deleted, make sure the folder or files are already present before creation of the lifecycle management rule.
- The rule applies only to files created after it was created. before if it is present, it will not be deleted.
- Make sure If you are updating or new policy it may takes up to **`48Hrs`** to complete.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Code view:**

```
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "rule1",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "test/folder1/scores.json",
            "test1/folder1/file.json"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also check the any restrictions in place for the container or the blobs like [Immutability policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-version-scope?tabs=azure-portal) or the blob is leased.

**Reference:**
[azure - Lifecycle management rule not working for ADLS Gen2 Storage Account - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004999/lifecycle-management-rule-not-working-for-adls-gen2-storage-account) by Joel Cochran.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. In my code sample with my prefixes the file names are usually appended with timestamp at the end. So when I said event_ or events or sensors the rule should be checking for list of files stating with the name as listed is it ?

Comment: Yes, it will only check prefix of event_ or events or sensors and once the prefix matches it will be deleted.