# Azure storage deletion policy does not work

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I need to delete all blobs residing in a particular container in my storage account after 1 day since creation. To do that I have tried to set a policy but I cant make it work so far.

I have tried to create the policy both by using the azure portal and by using terraform. The policy code view shown in the portal is the following:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "delete_old_records_csv_files",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "queryresults"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have waited 2 days for the files to get deleted but they did not. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the location of the stored blob? Could it be that the set prefixMatch is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PeterBons. All blobs to be deleted in the container. I do not have any extra folders in that container. So with `prefixMatch = queryresults` I am attempting to point to all files in the container. Do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have waited 2 days for the files to get deleted but they did not. Is there something I am doing wrong?

- If the blobs are created before the creation of the lifecycle management rule they will not be deleted.
- To apply policy for existing blobs, you can move or copy them to a new container where the policy will be applied.
- Make sure If you are updating or new policy it may take up to **`48Hrs`** to complete.

**Portal:**

[image]

- Ensure that the blobs you trying to delete match the prefix `"queryresults"` as same as in the specified policy.
- Also check if any restriction is applied to a container or blob like [Immutablity policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-version-scope?tabs=azure-portal) and the blob is leased.

[image]

If everything is correct but still not being deleted, you can debug your storage account by using **`audit logs`** and if you get warning that will explain why the policy is not working.

**Reference:**
[azure - Lifecycle management rule not working for ADLS Gen2 Storage Account - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004999/lifecycle-management-rule-not-working-for-adls-gen2-storage-account) by Joel Cochran.